# How to do an "OneToMany(Field)" relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django

I know that there is no OneToManyField. But in this situation I need one.

I want to save many Image objects to one Advertisement object. How can I achieve this ?

I have the following situation:

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to="", default="", null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.image.url

class Advertisement(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user', null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ManyToOne` dependency. Have a look at official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) for more info.

```
class Advertisement(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user', null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

class Image(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to="", default="", null=True)
   advertisment = models.ForeignKey(Advertisement, related_name='advertisment', null=False)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.image.url
```

Comment: Hello @deathangel908 How to get images from advertisement object?

Comment: @FendiTriCahyono `Image.objects.get(adertisment_id=ID).image`